# How to get Traffic Data from Bing Maps API?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, bing-maps

I am trying to find the API to get the Traffic Flow from Bing Maps, but I can't find it.

I see that they have [Traffic API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441725.aspx) but it will only return Traffic Incidents.

I found the [TrafficManager Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712844.aspx) to use Traffic Flow API but I can't find Traffic Flow API. I am sure Microsoft has Traffic Flow API because they have mentioned it in [Bing Maps Traffic Coverage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj136866?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Is there an API to get Bing Maps Traffic Flow?

Comment: See answer given [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/13a116e9-e0dc-4b22-aa6c-4d1ce9ab74b9/get-current-traffic-flow-in-jsonxml-response?forum=bingmaps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible to retrieve granular per segment/route traffic information from Bing or the [XAML MapControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol). The MapControl does expose the `TrafficFlowVisible` property which controls whether traffic conditions are displayed on the map canvas.

Comment: When, What is the use of TrafficManager Class?

Comment: The TrafficManager class is for use with the Bing Maps V8 Web Control. It more or less accomplishes the same functionality as the TrafficFlowVisible property on the XAML MapControl combined with retrieving traffic incident information via the Traffic API you linked to and displaying incidents on the MapControl.

Comment: Is there is any other API to get RAW Traffic Data?

Comment: Microsoft and Google do not offer access to raw traffic data. Google does offer richer traffic APIs for [enterprise customers](https://enterprise.google.com/maps/), HERE offers a [Traffic API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/topics/introduction.html), and there are a number of [open data sources](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1767/data-of-vehicle-traffic) that provide vehicle and traffic data. [Uber Movement](https://movement.uber.com/cities) is another interesting effort that may be of interest to you.